# How can grub pass any custom variable into system enviroment?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, kernel, init

I want to identify which menu entry has been lauched in rc scripts.

So is it possible to pass any variable into my system via kernel argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the kernel command-line out of `/proc/cmdline`, which is set by grub.   That is the most direct way to access that data.  It may even include the details you want already.

Comment: That's good, but how can i add any items into kernel command-line without affecting of anything else?

Comment: I don't follow your question.  Grub sets the kernel command line, which appears to be what you are asking about.  How you configure grub is between you and your distribution.

Comment: OK. But my question is how to pass any variable. So how can i pass variable without affecting anything else?

Comment: Oh.  As long as whatever you add isn't a command line option that Linux recognises, it will be ignored.